# AngularJS Service to Return an Object Instead of a Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, q

I am trying to refactor my AngularJS code by having my service resolve a promise call that will automatically bind an object to to my scope.

```
// converting this:
imageService.getImages(userId)
.then(images => {
    $scope.images = images;
});

// into this:
$scope.images = imageService.getImages(userId);
```

My current solution I am trying to refactor is:

```
function getImages(userId) {
    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: '/a/images',
        params: { userId: userId }
    };

    return $http(config).then(onGetImagesSuccess, onGetImagesError);
}

function onGetImagesSuccess(response) {
    $log.info('Get image success', response);
    return response.data;
}

function onGetImagesError(response) {
    $log.info('Get image error', response);
}
```

I started playing around with `$q.defer()` and I got my `getImages()` to this following state. The problem is that I `imageService.getImages()` returns a Promise instead of the images. It is interesting that the list of images do get logged tho.

```
function getImages(userId) {
    const deferred = $q.defer();
    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: '/a/images',
        params: { userId: userId }
    };

    let call = $http(config).then(onGetImagesSuccess, onGetImagesError);
    deferred.resolve(call);

    return deferred.promise.then(images => {
        $log.info(images); // List of images does get logged
        return images; // Promise gets returned instead of the actual images
    });
}
```

I am wondering what do I need to do to refactor my code to get my `imageService.getImages()` to return a list of images instead of a Promise.

Comment: `Promise gets returned instead of the actual images` - yes, and it always will, because Promise chains always result in a Promise ... you can't make asynchronous results return synchronously (which is what you are attempting to do)

Comment: You are making an asynchronous request. There is no way for you to do what you are requesting. Why would you want to change the code?

Comment: I am just trying to refactor my code by moving more logic from my controller into my service. I am hoping that once the Promise is resolved, the service will return the result to my controller without me having to call `then()`.

Comment: "without me having to call then" sounds like you want to move to async/await then :)... or go back to callbacks HA

Comment: old but illustrative http://embed.plnkr.co/bx8eGvIFWhqdzCqpB7fb/ (beware you need try/catch... )

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by same recipe that is used in `$resource`. Empty object (array) is returned which is filled with data asynchronously. A promise should be returned as well, in case there's a need to know when and how a request finished:

```
var result = {
  data: [],
  promise: $http(...).then(response => {
    return Object.assign(result.data, response.data);
  })
};

return result;
```

Then `imageService.data` array is bound in view.

This pattern has its pros and cons. It is natural to have `then` in controller to unwrap promises.